# How to use variable from loop as parameter

Tags: bash, loops, wget

How do I use variable from loop as a parameter for wget?

```
#!/bin/bash  
    for i in {1..100}  
    do   
        for j in {1..1000}  
        do  
            wget -q [http://www.sitename.com/i/j.jpg]  
        done  
    done
```

the idea is to download all the image files from some site whose data was heavily corrupted (returns image or 404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$i` and `$j`to use the variables:

```
wget -q "http://www.sitename.com/$i/$j.jpg"
```

Comment: Lose the square brackets, they were probably in the question just to indicate a placeholder. Probably replace with double quotes in case the real URL contains any shell metacharacters.

Comment: Looks like OP got the hint, but I'll clean that up for posterity.